# Using "alpha"-style citations + having a numbered reference list

Tags: bibliographies, citing

In my document, I would like to use something that looks like the alpha bibliography style, i.e. have my citations displayed as [AB95]. However I need my list of references to be numbered, as in the following example:

1. [AB95] ...
2. [B07]  ...
3. [C01]  ...

etc.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the number yourself by modifying how `\@biblabel` works.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2022,
}
@article{riter,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2021,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{bibcount}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{%
  \thebibcount. [#1]%
  \stepcounter{bibcount}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{uthor}, \cite{riter}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

- Use this [file](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Egautam/sj/blog/20171114-bibtex-doi/halpha-abbrv.bst). Add this file in your project.
- Edit your `.tex` file:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \section{Introduction}
  This is an example of reference\cite{foo}. 
  \bibliographystyle{halpha-abbrv}
  \bibliography{refs}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Add a label in your bib file item. `label = {A1}`

  ```
  @article{foo,
  label         = {A1},
  author        = {Author, A},
  title         = {Example entry},
  journal       = {ArXiv e-prints},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eprint        = {1707.03780},
  primaryclass  = {physics.flu-dyn},
  doi           = {10.1010/doi-that-will-become-a-hyperlink},
  url           = {http://your.custom.url},
  year          = 2017,
  }
  ```